# Position a div based on the mouse position clicked

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I need to display a popup whose position is relevant to the clicked mouse coordinates in angular 4.
A perfect example would be creating events in google calendar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your HTML:

```
<div class="click-container" (click)="onMouseClick($event)"></div>
```

In your TS:

```
onMouseClick(e: MouseEvent) {
  console.log(e);
  //e.pageX will give you offset from left screen border
  //e.pageY will give you offset from top screen border

  //determine popup X and Y position to ensure it is not clipped by screen borders
  const popupHeight = 400, // hardcode these values
    popupWidth = 300;    // or compute them dynamically

  let popupXPosition,
      popupYPosition

  if(e.clientX + popupWidth > window.innerWidth){
      popupXPosition = e.pageX - popupWidth;
  }else{
      popupXPosition = e.pageX;
  }

  if(e.clientY + popupHeight > window.innerHeight){
      popupYPosition = e.pageY - popupHeight;
  }else{
      popupYPosition = e.pageY;
  }
}
```

Then you need to initialise the popup component with the relevant code.

Comment: How do I adjust the popup box when the coordinates am clicking is in the far end of the screen.Beacuse that hides my box

Comment: @SunithaPremakumaran I updated my answer to ensure popup is always fully visible on screen.

Comment: @SunithaPremakumaran I updated my answer again (using `e.pageX` and `e.pageY`) now so it works when page is scrolled. Let me know how it works for you.

Comment: perhaps you could provide a sample fiddle/jsbin which shows what exactly your issue is?